# REST APIs - How to create new Data types for ease of input validation

Tags: spring, rest

In my application I use certain data types repeatedly. For example I accept Phone number in multiple controller requests. I don't want to use String type in my request and repeat the same @Pattern again and again. Rather I would like to create a Phone type and use @Valid and Phone is of type String and I use @Pattern with phone number regex here. If the request accepts list of phone numbers client should be able to pass like
'''{
"phoneNumbers": [
"123456789",
"123456789"
]
}'''
Is it possible? if yes how the Phone type should look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [this library](https://github.com/rafasf/microtype) will help

Comment: Thanks, this look close. Can you please explain this class in README -                 
 ``` public class AccountNumber extends MicroType<String> {
  private AccountNumber(String value) {
    super(value);
  }
  
  public static AccountNumber accountNumber(String value) {
    return new AccountNumber(value);
  }
} ```

Comment: See my answer. Is there anything else that needs explaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this library](https://github.com/rafasf/microtype). It includes a Jackson module to handle deserialization of microtypes for you.

In your scenario, you would create a `Phone` type extending `MicroType<String>`. The only caveat, I think, is that you would need to provide a getter for the value property to be able to apply validation constraints:

```java
@Pattern(...)
protected String getValue() {
    return super.value();
}
```

Note that, if it's just the repeating of `@Pattern.regex` that's bothering you, an alternative solution is to create a custom `@Phone` constraint annotation:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Pattern(...)
public @interface Phone {
    String message() default "Invalid phone no";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for detailed explanation and sorry can't upvote as not enough reputations. I have added this in my Application.java                                                                                           ` @Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder){
ObjectMapper obj = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
TypeModule = new TypeModule();
obj.registerModule(module);
return obj;
} `  this is causing no uniquebeanFound error

Comment: (But you can accept the answer if you find it useful)